# Highlight the entire line length in Tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

This example works fine except that I want the highlighted region to span the width of the Text widget. My first thought was to pad the string with spaces using `ljust` but as the Text widget is going to be populated with different font types it's not going to work.

Is there a way of highlighting an entire line?

```
import tkinter as tk

def highlight(n):
    text.tag_add("highlight", "{}.0".format(n), "{}.end".format(n))

def remove_highlight(n):
    text.tag_remove("highlight", "{}.0".format(n), "{}.end".format(n))

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root, width=30, height=3, wrap=None)
text.pack()

text1 = "text"
text2 = "text2"

text.insert(tk.INSERT, "{}\n".format(text1))
text.insert(tk.INSERT, text2)

text.tag_configure("highlight", background="grey")
text.tag_configure("normal", font=("Arial", 12))
text.tag_configure("large", font=("Arial", 18))

text.tag_add("normal", "1.0", "1.end")
text.tag_add("large", "2.0", "2.end")

text.tag_bind("normal", "<Enter>", lambda event, n = 1: highlight(n))
text.tag_bind("normal", "<Leave>", lambda event, n=1: remove_highlight(n))
text.tag_bind("large", "<Enter>", lambda event, n = 2: highlight(n))
text.tag_bind("large", "<Leave>", lambda event, n=2: remove_highlight(n))

text.configure(state="disabled")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your highlight needs to include the newline character in order to span the full width of the widget. Add "+1c" (plus one character) to your second index:

```
text.tag_add("highlight", "{}.0".format(n), "{}.end+1c".format(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

using `+1lines` seems to work. I changed the two functions to

```
def highlight(n):
    text.tag_add("highlight", "{}.0".format(n), "{}.0+1lines".format(n))

def remove_highlight(n):
    text.tag_remove("highlight", "{}.0".format(n), tk.END)
```

and it seems to work fine.